# Comparing objects in C and C++

Tags: c++, c, comparison

I'm working on a project where I should instrument a program (written in C and C++) by inserting a print statement before
the statements that respect some criteria. Then, I should compare those values for different executions.
Since in C there are structures, while in C++ one can also define classes, I was wondering if there is a particular method that:

1. Permits to print primitives as well as complex data structures.
2. Permits to compare those values, for different executions, based on the format used by the *print module* (point 1.).

Just an example to clarify my question. Suppose that I have two different executions with this data structure:

```
struct Point {
   int x, y;
}

int main() {
    int k = random();
    Point p = foo(k);
    some_print(p); // Print the value of 'p' in a file

    return 0;
}
```

and then, another module will compare the two values of the point 'p' generated with the two executions.

Comment: It depends on how you want to go about printing. In general, every class needs to define a way to print itself... you don't get it for free. Same is true for comparison.

Comment: I have to only compare values in order to understand if they are equal or not. Obviously, I'm talking about the comparison of objects with the same type.

Comment: If you output the values to a file, surely you can compare the files afterwards. But to print `p` you will have to overload `some_print` for `Point`. There is no ready-made solution to that.

Comment: In C, there is no generic method that prints a structure, you need to print each member separately. You may be tempted just to print the bytes of the structure in hex (and that would work for the structure shown). However, a more complicated structure that contains padding cannot be dumped as bytes without invoking undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pragmatic C++-way of printing an object is defining a friend function:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Point& point) {
    return os << "(" << point.x << "," << point.y << ")";
}
```

It's usually class-specific so you need to implement it yourself; however, you might use some form of reflection. Particularly interesting is a CppCon-talk from Antony Polukhin [1] which gives reflection for POD types (like `Point` above). Generic reflection without external tools is N/A yet (as of 2016), there's a proposal on it. If you can't / don't want to wait, you can do multiple things:

1. **Parse C++ code:** ctags comes to mind.
2. **Macros:** It's relatively easy to write a FIELDS macro that defines a reflection class and the fields.

---

```
FIELDS(
    (int)x,
    (int)y
)
```

---

3. **Tuples:** Works only if you define all your fields on the same inheritance level. Inherit privately from a `std::tuple<>` which contains all your fields. Make const and optionally non-const getters for fields in terms of `std::get<>`. Then you can iterate over the types of your tuple.

(Would love to add more - pls. write comments if you have ideas.)

All the reflection methods also give you `operator==()` basically for free. Note that it's more pragmatic to add `operator<()` when possible. The former can be defined in terms of the first (albeit suboptimally: `a == b` iff `!(a < b) && !(b < a)` ) and the latter gives you `std::set<>` and `std::map<>`. Or you can do all the comparisons in terms of reflection.

[1] https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abdeAew3gmQ

Comment: Thank you for your detailed and useful reply, @lorro. I was thinking to parse the AST and generate the comparison on the fly. However, it could be complicated when the data structures are formed by too many fields (especially for their types, e.g. other _structs_). For this reason, I think that the best solution is to identify the object's types in a first stage, then add the comparing methods manually. It will be too complicated, and maybe unuseful to try to transform this task in an automatic way.

Comment: @Modfoo: Re: parse the AST: unless you're working for a firm writing compilers or similar tools, forget it. C++ AST is extremely complicated. Even ctags doesn't try to parse it completely. If you have to, try `gcc-xml` but be prepared...

Answer (score 0):

what you could do in c++, is to implement an equals method in your specific class.
That way what you could do is have a boolean equals() method, that checks if the objects are similar.
object1.equals(object2) could return either true or false.

to give an example with this answer, take a look at the following(an example i found online):

```
class car
{
private:
    std::string m_make;
    std::string m_model;

    bool operator== (const Car &c1, const Car &c2)
    {
        return (c1.m_make== c2.m_make &&
                c1.m_model== c2.m_model);
    }
}
```

something like this should be implemented in your own class.

Comment: `equals()` is alien to C++. Use `operator==()` instead.

Comment: right, overriding the operator itself makes for clearer functionality as well, thanks.